# How can a hard drive provide a host device with file/directory listings when the drive isn't spinning?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

On several of the newer hard rives that I've used, I've noticed that they will often stop spinning when not in use - presumably to save energy and to prolong its life. Interestingly, however, I've also observed that when a drive isn't spinning, I'm still able to get a directory listing from the top level of the drive - and folders below it. The drive will spin up when I then open an actual file - but how is it possible for a directory listing to be provided when the drive isn't physically spinning?

Comment: "several of the newer hard [d]rives [...] will often stop spinning" - I think consumer-grade hard drives have started to do that already in previous century, haven't they?

Comment: Hard drives don't provide directory listings by the way. They only provide bytes.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki: yes, HDD auto spin-down timeouts have been a thing for many years, configurable with ATA commands, e.g. on Linux with `hdparm` to send those commands to the drive.  Perhaps the OP means that external (or internal?) HDDs are starting to come with that as the default configuration, which most drives didn't used to.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Caching.

Both the operating system and drive have caches that buffer recently used drive data. If data is in the cache then it does not need to go direct to the disk platter.

Directory listing data will be quite likely to be buffered, especially if you have recently been to that directory.

Modern spinning drives have caches up to 64MB, while your operating system has almost all the memory not currently used by programs.

Comment: [Seagate IronWolf 8TB (ST8000VN004)](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/ironwolf-16tb-DS1904-16-2005US-en_US.pdf) has a cache of 256 MB.

Comment: And the root and top-level directories are likely to be cached, since they're referenced whenever absolute paths are used.

Comment: File Allocation Tables (FAT) are not that big. Couple MB at most. Basically always cached because every drive access will go there first.

Comment: For example I recently noticed that my windows keeps up to 10GB of recently accessed files in memory (Sometimes entire movies). Which makes perfect sense when the memory is not in use.

Comment: In particular, the OS can *smartly* read the entire file table at the time the drive is **mounted** and never touch it again. Modifications to files (e.g. rename, move) are first written to memory, then, at some point, flushed to the hard drive, which now requires starting the motors

Comment: aside from hardware level caching, there is also software caching in memory. and other forms.

Comment: @Nelson FAT hasn't been in widespread use for a long time

Comment: NTFS has [4% overhead](https://superuser.com/a/621052/997339) for the master file table while ext4 has [1.6% overhead](https://serverfault.com/a/310600) for the inodes. So on an 8TB NTFS formatted drive that'd be about 320MB overhead for ntfs. Since the Seagate Ironwolf has 256 MB of chache, most of it, especially subtrees used often, fit neatly into the drives NAND based cache.

Comment: Caching is used because the memory used for caching is way faster than the disk platter. The question only addresses reading, but as one of the previous comments mentioned, there is also write caching, which is one of the reasons that you should shut down your computer correctly before cutting the power and "eject" drives correctly before physically removing them.

Comment: @user253751 Actually, FAT32 has been in use on Windows, for the UEFI partition. I'm not sure about Linux. Yes, you can say "But that isn't FAT". Yes, but both work very similarly, with their limits. FAT32 is still in widespread use. Many consoles only support FAT32 (and maybe ex-FAT). Pendrive and memory cards usually come with ex-FAT, but formatting them with FAT32 for live environments/bootable installations is a common practice. Also, FAT just means "File Allocation Table". So, there are many file systems that use file allocation tables...

Comment: The vast majority of 2.5" drives now feature some rather aggressive head-parking as well (offloads the read head from the drive when "idle" - aka "hasn't been used for 10 seconds," usually). I can't say I've encountered one that entirely spins down (at least if you have a browser or something open), but yes, there's a cache on the drive itself *and* your OS will use whatever RAM you're not using as its own cache.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to traditional caching, it could be a [hybrid drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive) (SSHD). It looks like a normal spinning disk, but also contains a small SSD. The idea is to get the performance of an SSD for your most frequently accessed data at the price/size of a spinning disk.

The SSD can get as large as 8 GB, for example the awkwardly named [Seagate Firecuda](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/seagate-laptop-fam/laptop-sshd/en-us/docs/100802299c.pdf). If the data is on the SSD the spinning disk can stop.

Comment: Didn't this trend kinda flop because nowadays SSDs are just affordable enough in general?

Comment: @Hobbamok I wouldn't say it flopped. It's a transitional technology and the transition is almost over. Dual-drive hybrids are still viable if you need a lot of space on a budget.

Comment: Yeah, I guess for a bigger impact the transition period was too short, and imho the marketing also screwed it up, this tech would still be awesome in budget range laptops, but its nowhere to be found outside of custom builds :/

Comment: @Hobbamok CPU, memory, and capacity sell computers, not hard drive speed, so they cut corners. I used them to replace sluggish 5400 RPM stock drives. Now I'm about to give away my first SSD. I think the other answer is likely correct, I brought hybrids up for completion's sake.

Comment: Yeah, and thanks for reminding me, as a way to boost an older laptop they are probably still amazing when it comes to effective performance vs cost :)

Comment: @Hobbamok Going offtopic here: swapping a 5400RPM HDD with *anything* higher than 5400RPM or a cheap SSD with DRAM will help a lot on reviving old "tired" laptops. Just some cleaning, new thermal paste and a new HDD/SSD (preferably, an SSD) and it's good to go for a while. (Obviously, obvious RAM upgrades may be needed).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel yeah, that's what I've been doing, but with the budget for those fix-ups  being nonexistant to minimal, the choice used to be cheap (and quite small) SSDs, which come with their own host of problems that they fill up really quickly :/ If I find some hybrids for cheap that's definitely whats going into the next one. HDD for HDD it probably not worth the money (unless the drive itself is failing)

Comment: @Hobbamok Usually, it isn't that worthy, but a decent 7200RPM is way better than a 5400RPM or 4800RPM HDD, and may be more suited for people who use tons of space, for cheap (E.g.: family photos and videos, emails from multiple accounts). Also, I've never seen any SHDD in a 2.5" form factor.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel you haven't? The first one I bought for my Tower PC was 2,5'' by complete accident even, so I never thought about that not being the default. A quick google search shows me that there are a lot of them out there (nowadays), even from reputable manufacturers (as opposed to that first one lol, I can't believe that thing still works). and it makes sense since the actual stuff in SSDs is pretty small anyway

Comment: @Hobbamok I haven't, and it was quite hard to find an example. I found the Seagate Momentus XT ST500LX003, and it was hard to find it. I guess it is just Google being Google...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, I used Seagate Momentus XTs. I think they rebranded it as "Laptop SSHD". There's also Firecuda and Enterprise Turbo SSHDs in 2.5". Seagate seems to be the last one still doing SSHDs. Now an M.2 SSD is nearly as cheap, if you have the slot.